# Visualise a image after filters in MATCONVNET

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

i am trying to visualise my images after applying the filter on it using matconvnet from the tutorial http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn/. i am using the command :

```
figure(3) ; clf ; vl_imarraysc(y_ds) ; colormap gray ;
```

but i am getting error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'vl_imarraysc'
```

i have checked the location of my kernel and i am in /matconvnet folder and added that folder in the MATLAB path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vl_imarraysc()` function is actually part of a separate library which you can download from [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/).  It's a handy utility for displaying grids of images.  However, if you don't want to download the library you can visualize the filters individually using the MATLAB `imagesc()` function.